# Python Value Error, Can't Match Shape of Arrays

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, odeint

I am trying to create a plot with numpy and I am running into a Value Error. I have checked the shapes of the arrays before they enter the loop and somehow they are coming out miss-shaped relative to one another. Here is my current code:

```
sol = np.zeros((partition, partition))
solA = np.zeros((partition, partition))
for i in range(partition):
    sol[:, i] = odeint(SolveMe, ic, timeSpace, args=(zeemanSpace[i],))[:, 1]
    solA[:, i] = (1/(time[-1]))*It.cumtrapz(sol[i:, 1], timeSpace)
```

With the previous declarations:

```
partition = 100     
time = [ti, tf]
zman = [qi, qf]
zeemanSpace = np.linspace(zman[0], zman[-1], partition)     
timeSpace = np.linspace(time[0], time[-1], partition)
```

I commented out the **solA[:, i]** in my for loop and run this test:

```
print(sol.shape)
print(solA.shape)
```

Which produces

```
runfile('/Users/taylor/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/Academia/Student Material/OU/Research/DPT of BEC/Work/Numerical/Gen X. & P/Zhang et al. Results/Scratch.py', wdir='/Users/taylor/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/Academia/Student Material/OU/Research/DPT of BEC/Work/Numerical/Gen X. & P/Zhang et al. Results')
(100, 100)
(100, 100)
```

When the previous line in the for loop is uncommented, the following error is produced:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (99,) into shape (100,)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check the RHS of that asignment line.

Comment: Show the full error with traceback.  and test ALL relevant arrays

Comment: The error is tell you/us that `solA[:, i]` has shape (100,) (which is obvious).  but `(1/(time[-1]))*It.cumtrapz(sol[i:, 1], timeSpace)` has shape (99,).  Does that make sense to you?  I can't perform that calculation to determine why.  That's up to you to figure out.  It should be obvious that a (99,) array cannot be put in a (100,) shape slot.

Comment: I understand the error, and I am going through the other arrays. Thank you for your help!